# How to import Kmail filters into Evolution?

Tags: filter, evolution, kmail

Is there a way to import filters defined in Kmail into Evolution? I know how to export them (Tools → Import/export → Kmail/config), and extract the filters (extract `config/filters` which describes them in `.ini` format); but I don't know how to import filters into Evolution.

Comment: It's hard to find some specific procedural for both clients, but searching a little bit (I think you already did too) you might try to get those Kmail filters following this [steps](https://eyemeansit.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/how-to-import-your-old-kmail-filters/)

Also, can you check if Kmail has the same section as this [manual](https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-export-and-import-message-filters-of-thunderbird/)
says, and you define the export setup to Evolution.
Good luck.

Comment: @MauricioReyes Yeah, I did get as far as exporting from Kmail: You do `Tools / Import/export / Kmail/config` and then unzip the resulting file. It will have `config/filters` which describes them in ini format. But even if I could transform those into an Evolution compatible format, no idea how to import.